# Ошибки до нажатия кнопки

Tags: php, html, jquery

Возникла проблема,есть скрипт,который проверяет символы,длину логина и пароля.Используется Jquery Validation.Так вот,когда я специально пишу логин и пароль на кириллице, скрипт проверяет только пароль и выдает ошибки,а ошибки логина выдает только после нажатия кнопки submit.Помогите пожалуйста.Вот сам скрипт:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function()
        {
        $.validator.addMethod('LoginSymbols', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional( element ) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test( value );
        }, 'Логин должен состоять только из латинских букв или цифр!');

        $.validator.addMethod('PasswordSymbols', function (value, element) {
        return this.optional( element ) || /^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/.test( value );
        }, 'Пароль должен состоять только из латинских букв или цифр!');
            // Validation
            $("#sky-form").validate(
            {                   
                // Rules for form validation
                rules:
                {
                    username:
                    {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 3,
                        maxlength: 20,
                        LoginSymbols: true
                    },
                    password:
                    {
                        required: true,
                        minlength: 6,
                        maxlength: 20,
                        PasswordSymbols: true
                    }
                },

                // Messages for form validation
                messages:
                {
                    username:
                    {
                        required: 'Вы не ввели логин!',
                        minlength: jQuery.format("Логин должен состоять как минимум из {0} букв или цифр."),
                        maxlength: jQuery.format("Логин должен состоять максимум из {0} букв или цифр.")
                    },
                    password:
                    {
                        required: 'Вы не ввели пароль!'
                    }
                },                  

                // Do not change code below
                errorPlacement: function(error, element)
                {
                    error.insertAfter(element.parent());
                }
            });
        });         
    </script>
```

Comment: встречный вопрос, не по теме, просто интересно: а какое вам дело из чего состоит пароль пользователя? о_О

Comment: @Dmitry V, не сохранять же пароль в кириллице

Comment: Пароль вообще нельзя сохранять, только его хеш (причем не md5). А хешу без разницы что там было: кириллица, знаки препинания..

Comment: @Dmitry V я предпочитаю хэшировать пароль в латиннице

Comment: Я понял, окей. Вопрос снят.